# How do we get user's time zone offset integer in Apex or Formula Field?

Tags: apex, formula, timezone, formula-field

### How do we get user's time zone offset integer in Apex or Formula Field?

For example, a user's personal information time zone

```
(GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York)
```

### should return `-4`.

---

### More information:

My requirement to have a `commandButton Apex class` which assigns custom object records to Users if the

```
custom object's state's time zone == the current user's time zone.
```

Hence, I created two fields on my custom object:

1. `State__c` - for 2 letter USA state code
2. `GMT_Offset__c` - formula field which maps all USA states to a time zone offset integer

However, I am unable to get the current user's time zone offset integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaceySnr [posted a solution to this problem on his blog](https://laceysnr.com/time-zones-hurt-my-brain-one-way-to-get/) a while back. AFAIK there have not been any timezone API changes since then that would render his solution obsolete.

Just beware - it's pretty rare to actually need the user's timezone offset, there is often a better way to achieve what you're trying to do either via VF or via non-offset-modified dates. If in doubt, post more info on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I have added more information of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Interesting requirement! The solution here should do just fine for it.

Comment: Link to the solution is broken as of Jan 2020 :-/

Comment: Updated link: https://laceysnr.com/time-zones-hurt-my-brain-one-way-to-get/

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party, but in trying to tackle the same problem I arrived at the approach below for getting the exact value of the time zone offset. I hope this becomes useful if you ever face the same problem in the future (such as trying to render things correctly in Visualforce).

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
Long offset = DateTime.newInstance(now.date(), now.time()).getTime()
    - DateTime.newInstance(now.dateGmt(), now.timeGmt()).getTime();

System.debug('offset (milliseconds): ' + offset);
    // -14,400,000 for EDT (America/New_York)

System.debug('offset (hours): ' + (offset / (60 * 60 * 1000)));
    // -4 for EDT (America/New_York)
```

Comment: Can you explain how (offset / (60 * 60 * 1000) can convert gmt to -4GMT? What formula can I use to get +7 or +8 GMT?

Comment: Hi @compski the time zone offset is defined as the amount of time that must be added to the time expressed GMT to derive the _local_ time. `DateTime` objects track time at the level of milliseconds, so by default the arithmetic gives back the offset in _milliseconds_. To convert from ms to hours, the math is _offset in ms_ * (1 sec / 1000 ms) * (1 min / 60 sec) * (1 hr / 60 min).