# Date and Time stamp value should be updated in the field

Tags: workflowrule

I have to update the value of a text field on the Order object using Workflow Rule Field Update based on the time the record was created or last updated.

> The datetime stamp should be in the format:
>
> YYMMDDHHmmSS

```
for example:

171031121052
```

I have tried using this formula:

```
RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT( $System.OriginDateTime ),4),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT($System.OriginDateTime),7),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT($System.OriginDateTime),10),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT($System.OriginDateTime),13),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT($System.OriginDateTime),16),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT($System.OriginDateTime),19),2)
```

**but i got
000101000000**

in wrong format,

> can anyone suggest the answer according to today the record is created
>   or updated according to system time

please suggest this formula also, tried to working

```
RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT( now() ),4),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(now()),7),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(now()),10),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(now()),13),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(now()),16),2) 
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(now()),19),2)
```

Comment: please anyone guide me for the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.formula_date_time_tipsheet.meta/formula_date_time_tipsheet/formula_examples_dates.htm), to get the hour, minute, and second from a Date/Time field as a numerical value, use the following formulas where TZoffset is the difference between the user’s time zone and GMT. For hour in 24–hour format:

So you can use a formula like this. Update the formula as per your need.

```
TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) 
& 
IF(LEN(TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))=1,'0'&TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))),TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW())))) 
& 
IF(LEN(TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))=1,'0'&TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))),TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))
& 
IF(
  OR(
    VALUE( MID( TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) = 0,
    VALUE( MID( TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) = 12
  ),
  "12",
  TEXT( VALUE( MID( TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) 
   -
   IF( 
     VALUE( MID( TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 
     0, 
     12 
   ) 
  )
)
&
MID( TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - TZoffset ), 15, 2 )
&
MID( TEXT( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW()) - TZoffset ), 18, 2 )
```

To calculate the TZoffset refer to this [SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/how-do-we-get-users-time-zone-offset-integer-in-apex-or-formula-field) link.